# How to append to existing log file instead of overriding?

Tags: playframework

Below are the details given in conf/application.conf

## Root logger:

logger.root=ERROR

## Logger used by the framework:

logger.play=INFO

## Logger provided to your application:

logger.application=DEBUG

On server restart we are forced to take the backup of the existing log file as the existing file gets overridden instead of logs gets appended.

1. How to configure so that the log info gets appended instead of overridden?
2. Do we need to create and configure appender separately in log4j.properties or log4j.xml?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of play framework are you using?

Comment: Salem, i'm using 2.4 version